# No autocomplete popup in JSP files for snippets

Tags: sublimetext2, code-snippets, sublimetext3

I made a bunch of snippets I want to use when I'm editing .jsp files in Sublime Text 2.

When I edit a JSP file (syntax: JSP) the autocomplete function doens't work. When I change the syntax to "Java" the autocomplete works.

Plan B: it does work with the JSP syntax when I hit 'c: tab'. But there is no autocomplete while typing like with the Java syntax.

I tried

- changing and removing the scope
- changing the tabTrigger to core-, not using ":", giving every snippet another trigger, giving every snippet the same trigger (so plan B works)
- placing the snippet files in \Packages\User\ and \Packages\User\Jsp\ folder

Snippet example:

```xml
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
<c:forEach items="\$\{${1}\}" var="${2}" varStatus="${3}" begin="\$\{${4}\}" end="\$\{${5}\}">
${6}
</c:forEach>
]]></content>
<!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
<tabTrigger>c:</tabTrigger>
<!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
<scope>text.html.jsp</scope>
</snippet>
```

Example screenshot: [image: the problem]

Comment: does the behavior change if you're already inside JSP tags and have written some other code? I suspect there might be an issue with scopes, as the JSP language definition is a subset of the Java one.

Comment: The snippet works for me when I save it in `Packages/User/Java/` and type `c: [TAB]`. This is with the JSP syntax. Are you trying to get the auto-complete window to pop up beforehand?

Comment: @MattDMo `c: [tab]` works indeed but I would like it to pop up beforehand while typing. So I can fuzzy search snippets like c-if, c-choose,...
It also doesn't work when I already have some code in the JSP file.