# Autocomplete in JSP files with JSTL

Tags: jsp, autocomplete, jstl, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Being recently switched to Sublime Text I notice the lack of JSP/JSTL support.
While almost every filetype has autocomplete I see it isn't supported for JSP files.

Example: when I have:

```
<c:forEach var="kitten" items="${kittens}">
    <c:set var="name" value="${kitten.name}" />
</c:forEach>
```

It would be great if I could get autocomplete for 'kitt...', 'nam...' , etc... You catch my drift?

- Is this not working because the scope for JSP files is 'text.html.jsp'? And not something like source.jsp?
- Can I do something about it? Is there a way to support this? Maybe I can make a plugin for it (any examples?)?

BTW: I have the same problem with snippets in JSP files: [No autocomplete popup in JSP files for snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17700676/no-autocomplete-popup-in-jsp-files-for-snippets)

Comment: Apparently sublimetext isn't that sublime. Java developers usually use full fledged IDEs like Eclipse/Netbeans/IntelliJ for that instead of simple text editors. As far as I know, they all supports autocomplete of EL variables to some (high) degree. By the way, your JSTL code snippet is invalid. There are no EL expressions.

Comment: @BalusC I'm more of a frontend guy but most of the time I also create the JSP view files. So it would be great if I had some IDE like functionality in my text editor. I think it's possible because I see these functionalities with other laguage syntax's. When I change the syntax of my file to Java it works but then my syntax coloring is off (so it is not an ideal solution).

Comment: I'm also a frontend guy. All of those mentioned IDEs have also a builtin text editor if that's all what you're after.